# Application gets crashes when executing automation test for android application using Appium

Tags: android, selenium, automated-tests, appium

I am trying to automate some mobile application tests running on Android device through **Appium**, **Selenium framework**. I've setup my test classes in **Selenium** and trying to start android driver using below desired capabilities. My **Appium** version is 1.4.16.1

```
public static void initialize() {
    // Created object of DesiredCapabilities class.
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    // Set android deviceName desired capability. Set your device name.
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "03157df388c7b934");

    // Set BROWSER_NAME desired capability. It's Android in our case
    // here.
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");

    // Set android VERSION desired capability. Set your mobile device's
    // OS
    // version.
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0.1");

    // Set android platformName desired capability. It's Android in our
    // case
    // here.
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

    // Set android appPackage desired capability. It is
    // com.android.calculator2 for calculator application.
    // Set your application's appPackage if you are using any other app.
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.pnc.ecommerce.mobile.finder");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.fisglobal.lfi.pnc.ui.MainActivity");

    try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),
                capabilities);

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Driver initialization failed", e);
        }
}
```

When I run the test on real Samsung device, application is opened and then get crashed as soon as it opens with a message  `PNC Stopped..`, my testing app is `PNC mobile app`

When I check the logs in Appium desktop console, I see below stuffs :

```
 << info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)

info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"23","automationName":"Appium"}
info: Console LogLevel: debug
Killed Node Server.
Appium server process ended
Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color
info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"23","automationName":"Appium"}
info: Console LogLevel: debug
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.pnc.ecommerce.mobile.finder","appActivity":"com.fisglobal.lfi.pnc.ui.MainActivity","browserName":"Android","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"03157df388c7b934","version":"6.0.1"}}
info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.3 (java 1.5)
info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : version
info: [debug] Didn't get app but did get Android package, will attempt to launch it on the device
info: [debug] Creating new appium session 4950142d-270c-433f-ba7f-c6fdea58f76a
info: Starting android appium
info: [debug] Getting Java version
info: Java version is: 1.8.0_131
info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe
warn: No app capability, can't parse package/activity
info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
info: [debug] Preparing device for session
info: [debug] Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device
info: Retrieving device
info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
info: Found device 03157df388c7b934
info: [debug] Setting device id to 03157df388c7b934
info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 03157df388c7b934 wait-for-device
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 03157df388c7b934 shell "echo 'ready'"
info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
info: [debug] Getting device API level
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 03157df388c7b934 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
info: Device API level is: 23
info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
info: [debug] Apk doesn't exist locally
info: [debug] Could not get strings, but it looks like we had an old strings file anyway, so ignoring
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 03157df388c7b934 shell "rm -rf /data/local/tmp/strings.json"
info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
info: [debug] Skipping install since we launched with a package instead of an app path
info: [debug] Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 03157df388c7b934 forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724
info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 03157df388c7b934 push "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\android_bootstrap\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
info: [debug] Pushing settings apk to device...
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 03157df388c7b934 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"
info: [debug] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 03157df388c7b934 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk"
info: Starting App
info: [debug] Attempting to kill all 'uiautomator' processes
info: [debug] Getting all processes with 'uiautomator'
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 03157df388c7b934 shell "ps 'uiautomator'"
info: [debug] No matching processes found
info: [debug] Running bootstrap
info: [debug] spawning: C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 03157df388c7b934 shell uiautomator runtest AppiumBootstrap.jar -c io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap -e pkg com.pnc.ecommerce.mobile.finder -e disableAndroidWatchers false
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap:
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Socket opened on port 4724
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Appium Socket Server Ready
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Loading json...
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
info: [debug] Waking up device if it's not alive
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["wake",{}]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Client connected
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"wake","params":{}}
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: wake
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":true}
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 03157df388c7b934 shell "dumpsys window"
info: [debug] Screen already unlocked, continuing.
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["getDataDir",{}]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"getDataDir","params":{}}
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getDataDir
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"\/data\/local\/tmp"}
info: [debug] dataDir set to: /data/local/tmp
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["compressedLayoutHierarchy",{"compressLayout":false}]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"compressedLayoutHierarchy","params":{"compressLayout":false}}
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: compressedLayoutHierarchy
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":false}
info: [debug] Getting device API level
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 03157df388c7b934 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 03157df388c7b934 shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n com.pnc.ecommerce.mobile.finder/com.fisglobal.lfi.pnc.ui.MainActivity"
info: [debug] Waiting for pkg "com.pnc.ecommerce.mobile.finder" and activity "com.fisglobal.lfi.pnc.ui.MainActivity" to be focused
info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 03157df388c7b934 shell "dumpsys window windows"
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 03157df388c7b934 shell "getprop ro.build.version.release"
info: [debug] Device is at release version 6.0.1
info: [debug] Device launched! Ready for commands
info: [debug] Setting command timeout to the default of 60 secs
info: [debug] Appium session started with sessionId 4950142d-270c-433f-ba7f-c6fdea58f76a
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 303 5351.163 ms - 74 
info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/4950142d-270c-433f-ba7f-c6fdea58f76a {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"6.0.1","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"appPackage":"com.pnc.ecommerce.mobile.finder","appActivity":"com.fisglobal.lfi.pnc.ui.MainActivity","browserName":"Android","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"03157df388c7b934","version":"6.0.1"},"appPackage":"com.pnc.ecommerce.mobile.finder","appActivity":"com.fisglobal.lfi.pnc.ui.MainActivity","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"03157df388c7b934","version":"6.0.1"},"sessionId":"4950142d-270c-433f-ba7f-c6fdea58f76a"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/4950142d-270c-433f-ba7f-c6fdea58f76a 200 3.558 ms - 705 {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"6.0.1","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"appPackage":"com.pnc.ecommerce.mobile.finder","appActivity":"com.fisglobal.lfi.pnc.ui.MainActivity","browserName":"Android","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"03157df388c7b934","version":"6.0.1"},"appPackage":"com.pnc.ecommerce.mobile.finder","appActivity":"com.fisglobal.lfi.pnc.ui.MainActivity","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"03157df388c7b934","version":"6.0.1"},"sessionId":"4950142d-270c-433f-ba7f-c6fdea58f76a"}
Killed Node Server.
Appium server process ended >>
```

Please help me to sort out this issue

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the test starts, try running `adb logcat` from the terminal.You can find the Java runtime exceptions in the logs that get continuously spewed out on the screen.If you will still be unable to sort out the details of the crash.Just do `adb logcat > logs` and as soon as the app crashes hit `CTRL+c` on the keyboard and paste the logs on this page.